# Why is the 5G rollout a problem in the USA but apparently nowhere else?

Tags: faa-regulations, avionics, easa-regulations, caa-uk-regulations

[The FAA is concerned that 5G cell phone signals could adversely affect radar altimeters on aircraft](https://www.avweb.com/aviation-news/faa-to-take-regulatory-action-over-5g-interference/).  This is because 5G signals are in the 3.7 to 3.98 GHz range, while radar altimeters operate in the 4.2-4.4 GHz frequency range. The worry is that the nearby cell signals will cause interference with avionics.  However the 5G roll-out in Europe is also under way but I haven't noticed any concerns raised by EASA or the CAA.  Why not?  Is there a difference in frequencies/equipment between the US and Europe?  Or have I just missed the news stories about potential problems outside the USA?

Comment: "nearby cell signals" - There's 200 MHz of separation!  If this sort of thing was going to be an issue, wouldn't we have long since seen issues with VORs from the FM broadcast stations in an immediately-adjacent band?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since you are asking specifically about the 3.7–3.98 GHz band, the answer is that most of the world uses the 3.3–3.8 GHz band. The 3.7–3.98 GHz band was seen as much less important until US operators (somewhat surprisingly) paid over $90 *billion* in an auction this year.

So, the US are the first (and at the moment only) ones to use this band, which is why it makes sense that they are also the first ones to worry about interference in this band.

However, the [French DGAC has also voiced concerns](https://france24.com/en/live-news/20210216-5g-phones-may-interfere-with-aircraft-french-regulator).

Comment: "most of the world uses the 3.3–3.8 GHz band" is inaccurate. The EU utilizes 3.4-3.8. Canada allocated 3.475-4, China is 3.3-3.6, but critically Japan has allocated 3.6-4.1, and South Korea allocated generally 3.4-4.

Comment: So how is the lower 3GHz used by the US right now? US is the first region in the world to use mm wave (~30GHz) as well. Unlike other regions, US seems really short on sub-6G, e.g. lower 3GHz and 5GHz.

Comment: @user3528438 AFAICT, the highest band currently used in the US for mobile networks is B41 (2.5GHz).

Comment: StephenS has provided a good answer however I'm going to accept this because Jörg specifically addresses the difference between the US and the rest of the world.  I guess my problem now is to find which stack I should use to ask if the handsets differ for different frequencies.

Comment: @DaveGremlin Let me know where you ask and I’ll answer. Short version: handsets sold in different regions support different sets of bands, but today they should all include a small subset that works everywhere as a last resort.

Answer (score 32):

If you read the FAA’s statements (not media reports) closely, you will find their complaint is merely that it hasn’t been proven *not* to be a problem, not that they actually expect a problem or have any rational basis to suspect it would be.

This follows the general hyper-conservative stance of the FAA: assume everything is unsafe until proven safe (at someone else’s expense), which has not been done in this case.

As a result, operators are prohibited from relying on radioaltimeters in areas where the 3.7-3.98GHz band is being rolled out, but they are still to monitor it. If no problems are reported after some period, they will rescind the order.

Comment: +1  My guess was that there would be a standard 5G frequency and the FAA would look at evidence from other nation's 5G rollouts when making a decision, but regulation is never that simple in aviation.

Comment: @DaveGremlin Every country is free to allocate its radio spectrum however it wants, and the result is a mess of different mobile bands. In the olden days, you even had to rent a local phone when you traveled because your own might not support the bands of the country you were visiting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the FAA assumed the 737 Max was safe until repeatedly proven unsafe. Hyper-conservative is not the word I would choose. I might consider this more of an over-reaction in the wake of the 737 Max affair. As Vikki already noticed, it's 200 MHz separation. 5G specs allow a 100PPB+15Hz frequency error, i.e. 415 Hz at 4 Ghz. That's 500.000 times less than the 200.000.000 Hz separation.

Comment: @MSalters - I might be wrong, but I think that's just for the carrier frequency.  As soon as you modulate the carrier (in order to carry information), the bandwidth increases.

Comment: And filters (used in receivers, such as the receive portion of an altimeter), are not perfect.  That means that an altimeter using 4.2 GHz MAY see some leakage or bleed over from a 3.98 GHz cell phone signal.

Comment: @MSalters Boeing provided the FAA with tons of (falsified) data that proved the MAX was safe. That’s different from 5G on the 3.8GHz band, where there is currently no data at all.

Comment: "not that they actually expect a problem or have any rational basis to suspect it would be."  False.  [RTCA Paper No. 274-20/PMC-2073](https://www.rtca.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/SC-239-5G-Interference-Assessment-Report_274-20-PMC-2073_accepted_changes.pdf) reports modeled interference with radio altimeters arising from intentional 3.7-3.98 GHz and spurious 4.2-4.4 GHz emissions by 5G radios.  Worst-case interference is more than 40 dB over the measured safe interference limit for those altimeters.  This report was published October 2020 (before the FCC's C-band auction).

Comment: OT: **#TIL** that the aviation industry's charming term for a plane crash is "CFIT", or "Controlled Flight into Terrain".

Comment: @FeRD Not all crashes are CFIT.

Comment: @MSalters 200MHz corresponds to 5 ns in the time domain, or 2.5 feet uncertainty in a radar signal round trip. So the receiver may be fairly wideband to keep good time domain accuracy. I'm not sure you want more altimeter error than that at touchdown. Anyone have info on actual radar altimeter accuracy?

Comment: and sources e.g. https://www.aviationpros.com/home/article/10387134/radio-altitude-the-instrument-of-choice put radar altimeter accuracy close to ground at 2 feet, or (other sources) 0.75m (2.5 feet). So there may well be time domain effects requiring high bandwidth.

Answer (score 6):

**The FAA wants to draw attention to and monitor any effect of 5G on aviation safety so it detects issues now, while they are minor, and not later, as the number of 5G devices per square mile grows and the effects get stronger.**

The rest of this is just my theory on why it might be different by nation.  In the USA, there has always been an abundance of extreme caution about allowing radio equipment to proliferate in the market before ruling out the potential that it could later have to be banned or heavily restricted.  You want to know up front.  This eliminates waste in producing such equipment.  The national difference here is the **"regulatory takings"** doctrine, which I don't think much of Europe has.  That is where, if a person or company bought a perfectly legal thing that had a perfectly legal use, and that use is later banned or restricted in a way that decimates its value, it's considered "taken" by the government, even if they didn't physically take hold of it.  This means it must be for the public good, and even then, they have to pay.  If you ban beef, you've "taken" the full value of all the cows currently being raised for beef, and would have to compensate farmers their full value under the Constitution.  Ban driving, pay for all the cars.  There are still exceptions to seat belt laws for extremely old cars that existed before the seat belt law - Congress keeps those exceptions because if they didn't have that exception, the law would be a "taking" of antique cars and they'd have to pay for them.  **Ban 5G later when problems are discovered, pay for all the towers** (and all the phones' price difference from the 4G models most likely).  Because the financial risk of proliferating infrastructure that will have to be banned falls on the agency banning it, they have an incentive to actually look ahead before more is built.  If you are a European leader, ignore the problem until it is a crisis, then ban 5G, and make the telco's take the loss.